# Multiple definition error in Dev-C++

Tags: c++

I initialised some arrays in a file called `Fares.cpp` in my project. When I try using `#include "Fares.cpp"` in my `main.cpp` file (where the main code for the project is) in Dev-C++, the compiler gives an error saying “multiple definition”. I don't know what to do, please help.
I don’t know much about macros, extern etc.

Comment: Only header files (`.h`, `.hpp` etc.) should be included. Show us your code if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/cpp/hfiles.html

Answer (score 2):

Try including `"Fares.h"` instead of `"Fares.cpp"`. `#include` is usually used to include *header files* which usually contain variable declarations and function prototypes. Check this link for more info: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/

Comment: it says there is no such file called Fares.h. as the project file got saved as fares.cpp

Comment: can u write ur email i will send u the entire project, u try to run it and see what the problem is. if u dont want to write down ur email here u can send me a dummy mail at agnibha28@gmail.com

Comment: I'll send you an email

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, .c  and .cpp files are related to single  compile unit (module, etc.), processed by compiler separately. Include meant to add  files called "header files" or "include files" to the file scope, making *declarations*, inline functions definitions and *type definitions* in them being available to syntax analyzer of compiler.
Declarations include:

- Function declaration
- Template declaration
- Explicit template instantiation
- Explicit template specialization
- Namespace definition
- Linkage specification
- Attribute declaration (attr ;) (since C++11)
- Empty declaration (;) (since C++11)

To avoid multiple definition of same classes or functions, header files must use #ifndef blocks as "brackets"

```
// beginning of file.h
#ifndef SOME_UNIQUE_ID
#define SOME_UNIQUE_ID

// declarations , etc.

#endif
// end of file .h
```

There is nothing that prevents use of  different suffixes, it's matter of how  build process is organized. There is common agreement to name C  files .c, C++ - .cpp, standard C++ headers wouldn't have suffix at all, while all other headers  may have .h or .hpp. Include files that contain only inline functions sometimes are given .inc or .inl suffix instead of .h, but this isn't regulated in any way as far as I know

You can have only one definition per same scope with same ID. More of even while you may have several file scopes, for each .cpp a non-static declaration would generate duplicate IDs that would cause link-time error. You really should avoid using .cpp as include file, because in most build environments  compiler would attempt to link it multiple times - for each use in #include and  as separate module as well.

In your case you should put declarations of your arrays into .h file in form like this:

```
// fares.h
#ifndef FARES_H_
#define FARES_H_  // this will not allow declaration to be repeated

extern int gYourGlobalArray[100];

#endif
```

Word extern will tell the compiler that the symbol is defined elsewhere and would be found on link stage, the object should be **static or thread storage duration**, which in our case true as we declare global variable, and gets **external linkage**.  Fares.cpp will have "implementation" that must contain symbols that will not be repeated.

```
// Fares.cpp
#include "fares.h" // necessary only if you require something declared there
// keep in mind that some file systems are case sensitive, some aren't and
// will not distinguish between Fares.h and fares.h

int  gYourGlobalArray[100] = {};
```

That's actually defines thread duration storage for your array in file scope and allows it to be linked externally. Across entire project its identification should be unique (C++ compiler mangles names of some objects, e.g. functions, but in general you should avoid reusing IDs). If for some wild reasons ID in file scope  repeats  in different files but should not be linked externally, such storage should be declared `static`, that would disallow external linkage.

Declaring a static member of class usually either require similar definition  in .cpp file (without keyword `static`) or requires initialization within class body, provided compiler supports that.

Next you only should add fares.cpp to your project\makefile\whatever you are using as compiling environment.  fares.h goes into #include statements into .cpp or .h files that require it. #include statement technically just adds text of mentioned file to file wrote it in, exactly in that position.

Comment: so what u mean is i should write #ifndef Fares and #definese Fares in the beginning of the Fares.cpp file? and in the main file i should make the statement #include"Fares.h"??

Comment: it didnt work i tried that

Comment: can u write ur email i will send u the entire project, u try to run it and see what the problem is. if u dont want to write down ur email here u can send me a dummy mail at agnibha28@gmail.com

Comment: @Agni Added example to my answer, it should actually easy. I wonder what kind of tutorial totally omits that.  Try find.. dunno..text of Kerninghan and Richie's book (it is freely available)? It's on C but some basics are inherited. Or get Straustroup's book. It's ill-advised to use Borland tutorials..